# How to link with a WebDAV application in Unity?

Tags: 11.04, sharing, webdav

In Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick, I could go to the Places menu and click "COnnect to Server" to run a WebDAV server for my NextApp WebSharing Android application. But in Unity, I'm not sure how I achieve the same thing. I tried "Shared Folders" but it says I'm missing plugins. (I uninstalled Evolution and everything related to it, if that helps.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start Nautilus, in the menue go to: File-> Connect to server

Comment: Well rub my elbows and call me bearcat! I totally forgot about that because of the hidden global menu. Thanks a ton.

Comment: you're very welcome, I also have to search for stuff in Unity all the time :D