# Recommendations for a WebDAV client

Tags: software-recommendation, webdav

I am trying to get [additional functionality](http://www.umich.edu/~umctdocs/WebDAV.html) from a school website that can allow multiple file uploads/downloads via drag and drop between the site's Resources folders and my personal computer via a WebDAV client, versus downloading each individual file manually. However, this feature is only officially supported for Windows and Mac, or for 3rd-party clients for those operating systems. I would like to be able to use this feature with Ubuntu 11.04.

I have already taken a look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40243/how-to-link-with-a-webdav-application-in-unity), but had no luck with its answer...probably because it never asks me for my school password, and I can't find a way to input one.

If there's a way to do this using what's already installed by default, or from some other application, please let me know.

**UPDATE**: When I try connecting through Nautilus, I get the following error message, regardless of whether I picked WebDAV (http) or Secure WebDAV (https):

[image]

And just to reiterate, at no point does it *ever* ask for my password.

Comment: I can't see a file > connect to option under nautilus. Can someone please send a screenshot? see screenshot [here:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6PH8BRtYXQoRENRcWRZVHlXWlU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @user2851108 I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Beta 2 currently, but there it should be in the [menubar](http://imgur.com/Uur6RHR). (You could probably find it using the HUD by tapping Alt, too.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Nautilus (the file browser), select File > Connect to ... and select WebDAV. Enter the information you need, such as a host name, a directory, port and username. Check the box to create a bookmark, and you'll find it in your Files and Folder lense and in the left pane in Nautilus.

You'll be able to use your WebDAV share as if it were a local folder.

Comment: I get an error message when I try this, for which I've added a picture above.

Comment: Right. Don't add https:// to the address. Only the hostname.

Comment: Thanks for the tip...regular WebDAV still wouldn't work, but selecting Secure WebDAV did the trick. It finally asked me for my password and I was logged on. Thanks!

Comment: "HTTP Error: Found" What does that even mean?!

Comment: Is that a precise error message? Just to be sure, you should have something like davs://username@www.example.com/directory/goes/here.

Comment: It seems that if the root directory of the webdav share isn't the root directory of the server then this doesn't work, resulting in the "HTTP Error: Found" message (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/975308 ).

Comment: So how would I mount this to a directory?

Comment: It is mounted in /run/user/USERID/gvfs. On a typical PC, your user is 1000, so it would be /run/user/1000/gvfs. If you want to access it from your home, make a directory "gvfs" and use "sudo mount --bind /run/user/1000/gvfs /home/YOUUSER/gvfs.

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu 14.04:

1) Open Nautilus (File manager)

2) Click on 'Connect to Server'

3) As server address enter:

```
davs://<username>@<webdav_address>
```

It is important that webdav_address doesn't contain the protocol. So for example if your web url is: `https://example.com/webdav`and your username is alice, the corresponding address for the server will be:

```
davs://alice@example.com/webdav
```

Comment: Im getting: Unhandled error message: HTTP Error: Could not connect: Connection refused

Comment: Maybe you have to specify the port?

Answer (score 3):

All of the server connections are handled in the same way in nautilus. You fill out the data for nautilus to connect to the remote server at which point it will be added as a bookmark to the bookmarked folders list.

The first time you try to connect to the server **if** it is password protected you will be asked to provide the password and you will be asked whether you want to save the password permanently, for the current session or forget immediately. Once the server has been mounted it can be browsed like any other folder on your system.

Hope this helps

Comment: The server should be password-protected, as indicated in the Windows setup instructions for any of the given clients. And yet it doesn't ask for one in Nautilus, but instead gives me an error window I added a picture of above.

Answer (score 1):

## Use directly the protocol `webdav://`

Often you can use directly the protocol `webdav://` in your file browser.
Nowadays under kubuntu, for example, it's enough to write in Dolphin instead of a local path the address required with the protocol `webdab://` before.

For example,

```
webdav://192.168.1.10/remote.php/webdav/
```

It will prompt for username and password, then you will deal with it in a manner similar to a local path.

Notes:

- Working on Kubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
- Dolphin (currently Version 17.12.3)
- A local instance of `webdab` under `nextcloud` accessible with an address similar to
  `192.168.1.10/remote.php/webdav/`

Answer (score 1):

Things have changed since the other answers on Nautilus running on later versions of Ubuntu

The acceptable connection string for WebDAV servers is like this.

```
dav://192.168.1.8
```

It'll ask for username and password.

Or if you need to specify user in the connection string itself.

```
dav://<username>@<address>
```

Answer (score -2):

This looks more like a windows name resolution problem... it cannot resolve the netbios name of the server.  It should work with te IP address however.

-To mount a windows share on a DHCP network, it is convenient to be able to mount by netbios name... it's very easy:

1) Edit your /etc/nsswitch.conf file with your preferred editor (gedit, kate, nano, vim, etc)... search through the file and look for the line that looks something like this:

hosts:      files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4

...and add "wins" to the end of the line so it looks something like this:

hosts:      files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] **wins** dns mdns4

2) Save the file.  Note: "wins" MUST come before "dns" if you are using the openDNS service.

3) Now you'll need to install **winbind**

Code:
sudo apt-get install winbind

4) Reboot, or restart your network.

Comment: I think it looks more like he's typed in https:// in the host field, which makes the address davs://username@http://hostname, which is incorrect. -1

Comment: You're very fast to downvote an answer that absolutely does no harm. I quote what it says in the Privileges Page:"Downvoting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing."

Comment: Well, your answer seemed to be obviously wrong. If it was only a small error, then I would've recommended an edit. But in this case, that would mean changing everything since the main assumption was wrong.